# Append missing extension to result of QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Using `QFileDialog`, I want to prompt the user for a filename and add the extension if it is missing.

One suggestion was to just manually add the extension after the fact. The problem with this approach is that the user may not be warned that they are overwriting a file (for example, *test.txt* exists,  the user enters *test* and is not prompted that they are actually overwriting *test.txt*)

I have read all the documentation on `QFileDialog` and have not had any success. I've tried `setDefaultSuffix`, but the result of `fileDialog.getSaveFileName()` did not contain the extension.  Can someone provide an example of how to do this successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like this functionality is not available when you're using the "native" file dialog. However, it works just as you expected if you use the Qt file dialog.

Here's how you can use the Qt file dialog:

```
QFileDialog saveDialog;
saveDialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptSave);
saveDialog.setDefaultSuffix("txt");
saveDialog.exec();
QString file = saveDialog.selectedFiles().first();
```

As an alternative, you can implement your own overwrite validation:

```
QString file;
do 
{
  file = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName();
  if(!file.endsWith(".txt"))
  {
    file.append(".txt");

    if(QFile::exists(file))
    {
      if(QMessageBox::Yes != QMessageBox::question(NULL, QString(), "Confirm overwrite?", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No))
      {
        file.clear();
      }
    }
  }
} while (file.isEmpty());
```

Comment: Thanks.  The first sample worked like a charm, in both native and the QT dialog, actually.  I guess the `saveDialog.getSaveFileName()` shortcut function doesn't quite work the same.